# I need this code to copy lines based on criteria from Col "A" and Col "J". This is code I copied from my other worksheet. Thanks

Tags: excel, vba

This code copies data from an imported text file to multiple worksheets. I need it to copy items not only from "COL J" but also "COL A" so that only data from a single organization goes to the next sheet.  The data from column A that needs to be copied are items marked "354", more specifically I need only the "354" lines with time less than "750" from column J.  Thank you.

```
Sub Daily354()

    Dim i, lastRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lastRow = Sheets("Imported Text File").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Sheets("Daily 354").Range("A2:S50000").ClearContents

    'Call AutoFilterDaily

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        If Sheets("Imported Text File").Cells(i, "J").Value < 750 Then
            Sheets("Imported Text File").Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Daily 354").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If

    Next i

    Worksheets("Daily 354").Activate
    'Call Add_Borders
    Call DailyNoFHR
    'Call Formatting_Table
    'Call Hide_ColumnsDaily
    Call Add_Type_Mx
    'Call AutoFilterDaily
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the If statement to be:

```
If ((Sheets("Imported Text File").Cells(i, "J").Value < 750) And (Sheets("Imported Text File").Cells(i, "A").Value = 354)) Then
    Sheets("Imported Text File").Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Daily 354").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
```

The only thing I'm not sure about is whether or not column A is numeric. If it is then you can use what I posted here. If column A is text then you'll need double quotes around the 354, like this "354".

Comment: It worked!.  And now it seems so simple, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's actually not working.  I'm getting either a syntax error, of "Expected Next or Goto"

Comment: I've updated my answer. If it still doesn't work then edit your code to show what you have now.

Comment: My edits won't make it through my employers filters.   And its pretty difficult to edit the code through my phone, lol.  That being said, I inserted your edits and I am still getting the error, however when only the first condition needs to be met, everything works fine.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: I forgot to add that column is a string because it's actually 354th so I wrapped it with "" like you said to do.

Comment: When you get a chance copy and paste exactly what you have that is getting the error into a comment or the question.